# Can I use a 1040ez if I filed an 83(b) for stock on a vesting schedule?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 83b-election, form-1040

I filed an 83(b) earlier this year for stock I received on a vesting schedule. I purchased the stock at fair market value, so when I filed the section 83(b), I earned net zero dollars. I have not sold any of this stock.

On my current tax return, all my income comes on my W2 and $2 of interest from a savings account. Can I file a 1040ez, or do I need to file a 1040 with zero reported investment income?

Comment: You can use 1040EZ.

Comment: Don't forget to include a copy of your 83(b) election paperwork with your tax return.

Comment: @user102008 why is this not an answer?

Comment: @littleadv: It was too short ;)

Comment: @user102008 "You can most definitely undeniably surely use 1040EZ". now it will work, try it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 1040EZ.

If there were any difference between the purchase price and the fair market value (which there wasn't in your case), it would have been listed as income on your W-2, and you would report it as wages on your tax return, which can be done on 1040 or 1040A or 1040EZ. You have not sold anything, so there would not be "investment income" to report anyway.

Comment: My refund has just been approved. Thanks all for the help!